# corona: how to target corners on landscape app?

Tags: lua, anchor, coronasdk

I'm having issues with setting object positions with anchor points. I have a landscape oriented app and I want to place buttons and images down in both bottom corners in X but when I set up the anchors they either appear way off screen or too high up.

So what I am asking is how can i set up anchors to position buttons at both bottom corners of a landscape phone? what values works best for getting it as close as possible to either locations?

I have seen a few other posts about anchor points but Its not clear whether its for portrait or landscape.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: here is my code. The result is that the image is off screen in the bottom right corner of the device.

```
prevImage = display.newImageRect("images/back_icon.png", 40,43) 
prevImage.anchorX = 0.5;
prevImage.anchorY = 0.0; 
prevImage.x = display.contentWidth
prevImage.y = display.contentHeight
group:insert(prevImage)
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and indicate the resulting position it caused on display. This effect is in Corona simulator, correct?

Comment: Yes show the code to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Sorry about that guys. the effect is happening in both simulator and device. Also, i found this: https://developer.coronalabs.com/code/continue-using-setreferencepoint-set-new-anchor-points-graphics20                                             is this viable to use in a published app? will there be errors if i use this to position images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anchor point of 0.0 means Top or Left (depending on X, Y).  A value of 0.5 is the center and a value of 1.0 is the right or bottom.

To use display.contentWidth and display.contentHeight to position something at the bottom right, you would want the anchors to be 1.0 and 1.0.

```
prevImage = display.newImageRect("images/back_icon.png", 40,43) 
prevImage.anchorX = 1.0;
prevImage.anchorY = 1.0; 
prevImage.x = display.contentWidth
prevImage.y = display.contentHeight
group:insert(prevImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

From own experience, I would avoid to change anchorPoints with the objective of positioning objects.

You can easy align your imagens and buttons to the bottom of your screen without changing their anchors by using the following code:

```
-- gets the real corner positions (when using auto-content scale)
_G.LEFT_X = display.screenOriginX
_G.RIGHT_X = display.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX
_G.TOP_Y = display.screenOriginY
_G.BOTTOM_Y = display.contentHeight - display.screenOriginY

-- positioning the image on the bottom right
prevImage.x = _G.RIGHT_X - prevImage.contentWidth*0.5
prevImage.y = _G.BOTTOM_Y - prevImage.contentHeight*0.5
```